# When should I use inherited scope and when should I not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When creating a directive, When should I use inherited scope (i.e `scope:true`) and when I should not use it (i.e `scope:false` )

I **understand** the difference between scope types and know what each scope type does. But I don't understand when I should choose one of them rather than the other.

Comment: [This](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/02/11/mastering-the-scope-of-a-directive-in-angularjs/) will give you better idea..

Comment: @RayonDabre, Thanks, however, that link explains the difference between the scope types and does not explain "when" should I use either of them. I need real case scenarios when should I use any of those types.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge following are the decision making criteria

1. Controller Scope Data Change  **-**(One direction)**->** Directive Scope Data Change : Use inherited scope. **Scope : True**
2. Controller Scope Data Change **<-**(Both direction)**->** Directive Scope Data Change: Use parent scope. **Scope : False**
3. Controller Scope Data Change -(No data change required)- Directive Scope Data Change: Use new isolated scope. **Scope : { }**

Suppose we have a functionality as:
 {Username} text box (Outside Directive) and 
 Hello {Name} (inside directive, and it is being displayed after the {Username} text box).

1. If the functionality is like changing {Username} should reflect {Name} then use 1.
2. If the functionality is like changing {Name} or {Username} will reflect vice versa, then use 2.
3. If there is no relation between {Name} and {Username} then use 3.

Though we can use 3(**isolated scope**) with 3 types of prefixes (**@**,**=**,**&**) by which we can pass the data between scopes and this is the best approach as per my knowledge.

Comment: I don't believe that it's totally correct, because in inherited scope (i.e scope:true), data binding is two way too If you use an object and bind to properties inside that object (ex: myModel.userName) rather than binding directly to the primitive type (i.e userName).

Comment: Yes, Dola. Absolutely right. But this is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.
Please see the following link. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: Best Article in this context. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2729-don-t-blindly-isolate-all-the-scopes-in-angularjs-directives.htm

Comment: That's a very nice article, However, it discussed isolate scope and didin't discuss other types.

For example, why some of the core directive (such as `ng-if` and `ng-repeat`) use `scope:true`. While other directives are not, what is the main reason that can tell me that I'd better use inherited scope rather than using the same scope?

Comment: Also, in the article you liked, it advises against using isolate scope for all cases, so it might not be best approach in all cases (specially that you can not add more than 1 directive with isolate scope on the same element), So, you might want to edit that in your answer ;)